# Using AppleScript and JavaScript to click a button that has no id

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I'm trying to use AppleScript to click a button that has no `id`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

The Sign in button on this site: https://intakeq.com/signin

Using this AppleScript code:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0].firstElementChild.click()"
```

Comment: dont get me wrong but id for html element must required if you are putting you element in dom

Comment: Please add some more information about what you expect or what is going wrong. There is no question in your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things for your question, but here's an answer that works in Safari:

```
tell application "Safari"
 --activate
 --(you can use with or without activate)
 do JavaScript "document.forms[0][7].click();" in document 1
 --7 is 'sign in' button
 --1 is email field;
 --2 is password field;
end tell
```

Perhaps it's not the best way to do this, but I've tested this and it works. And I've given you extra info about the email and password fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the button using its *class name*.

The following example AppleScript code assumes the target is in the current tab of the frontmost Safari window. Otherwise add appropriate code as necessary/required.

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block')[0].click();" in document 1
end tell
```